# Deleting Records in SQL server table prior to insert

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have a excel workbook that is a project plan template, that the PM fills in information and it gets loaded into a sql database. Currently the process if via a batch process that loads two tables(1 with 1 row of data and the other with multiple records). I am changing it to be a direct insert from excel into sql server via vba. I have the insert working but each table has a project id column which is the PK. The pm may update and save this file multiple times. The tables get updated with the most recent save information. I have solved this by adding a delete statement into my code and then inserting the updated record. This works great for the table with 1 record but I can't get the table with multiple records to work. It deletes the records and goes through the first loop of the insert but then goes back to the delete and removes the records.

I have attached the code for the multiple table delete and insert. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Public Sub exportprojdetaildata()

Dim stSQL As String
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String
Dim iRowNo As Integer
Dim targetedFieldNames As Variant
Dim rowData As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim sql As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim cvt As Double
Dim aField As String
Dim compare As Variant
Dim value As Variant
Dim dvalue As Long


With Sheets("Data")

    lastrow = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    'Open a connection to SQL Server
  conn.Open _
    "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=PWIRTPAUDD1HV8;Initial Catalog=STAR;User Id=STAR_USER;Password=dcistarrtp"

    'Skip the header row
    iRowNo = 2

     targetedFieldNames = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wks_TargetFieldNames.Range("targetedFieldNames").value), "," & vbNewLine)

     Do While iRowNo <= lastrow
        rowData = wks_BackgroundData.Range("A" & iRowNo & ":AV" & iRowNo).value

                compare = wks_BackgroundData.Range("AV2").value


        'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
            With rs
                .ActiveConnection = conn
                .Open "Select proj_id from dbo.STAR_DC_INITIAL_ProjectDetails_ExcelDevCopy where proj_id = " & compare

                wks_BackgroundData.Range("BA2").CopyFromRecordset rs


                .Close
            End With

                       value = wks_BackgroundData.Range("BA2").value

                If compare = value Then
                        sql = "delete from dbo.STAR_DC_INITIAL_ProjectDetails_ExcelDevCopy where proj_id = " & value


                conn.Execute sql
                Else

                sql = "insert into dbo.STAR_DC_INITIAL_ProjectDetails_ExcelDevCopy ("
                sql = sql & targetedFieldNames
    '            Debug.Print sql
                sql = sql & ") values (" & vbNewLine
    '            Debug.Print sql

        'couldn't do transpose since rowData represents a row, not a column
        For i = 1 To UBound(rowData, 2)
          aField = Replace(rowData(1, i), "'", "''")
      'escape single quotes
            Select Case i
                Case 1, 6, 16, 17, 23 To 47
                 '   cvt = CDbl(aField)
                    If aField = vbNullString Then
                        sql = sql & "Null," & vbNewLine
                    Else
                        sql = sql & aField & "," & vbNewLine
                    End If
                Case 2 To 5, 7 To 15, 18 To 22
                    sql = sql & "'" & aField & "', " & vbNewLine
                Case 48
                    If aField = vbNullString Then
                        sql = sql & "Null"
                    Else
                        sql = sql & aField
                    End If


                End Select
        Next i
       sql = sql & ");"
        'sql = sql & "');"

      ' End If

      conn.Execute sql

        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1

    Loop

  End If      


    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing


End With
```

End Sub

Comment: You shouldn't be using VBA to accomplish this.

Comment: What should I be using then?

Comment: If you are expecting the PM to do the update via Excel, then I understand why you are doing it with vba and agree with you.  You could add delete trigger on the 1 row (header) table, when a records gets deleted from there, it deletes the many row (detail) table.  Or add a foreign key and enable cascade delete on delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to be sure without seeing the data that you're trying to save, but I suspect you have a logic error.

The value for rowData is built up dynamically in a loop. which is correct.

```
rowData = wks_BackgroundData.Range("A" & iRowNo & ":AV" & iRowNo).value
```

but the values for compare and value are always read from the same location inside the loop. So the delete statement will be executed over and over again.

```
compare = wks_BackgroundData.Range("AV2").value
value = wks_BackgroundData.Range("BA2").value
```

Should compare and value not also be read dynamically?

```
compare = wks_BackgroundData.Range("AV" & iRowNo).value
value = wks_BackgroundData.Range("BA" & iRowNo).value
```

Or

you should move the delete statement outside of the loop, to ensure that it's only executed once

Or

you should keep a flag that will indicate that the delete has already been executed, and not execute it again.

```
hasExecuted = false <- OUTSIDE THE LOOP
...
...
If compare = value and hasExecuted = false Then
    sql = "delete from dbo.STAR_DC_INITIAL_ProjectDetails_ExcelDevCopy where proj_id = " & value
    conn.Execute sql
    hasExecuted = true
...
...
```

Also, I don't think you should have a IF x=y THEN delete ELSE INSERT. Should it not be IF x=y THEN delete, and always INSERT. With the else, it will only insert if the record didn't exist, but if it deleted the record, it will never insert the new one.

Hope that helps a bit

Comment: Thank you Spock. I was able to get it using the hasExecuted and changing the lookup to read dynamically.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it helped you d solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using VBA for new development work. If you need to constantly take this Excel document and insert it into a SQL Server database, then [use SSIS and some C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79mi31caAag) to easily make it a scheduled task via the SQL Agent, or simply do as the screen shot below suggests, which is a no-code and easily configurable import of flat files / database tables into SQL Server. Lastly, from a usability standpoint, There are many better methods to track Excel sheets or forms data (SharePoint, Excel 2013, Access, cloud/on premise drives) or using an internal WordPress distribution with some plugins like [WP-document revisions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpsTNSiJKis). [image: SQL Server Import Export]

Comment: I would love to do something like that but this existing development in that I am only adding a couple of subs into the workbook. This is a template then pm's pull down and use for their projects. These are used by numerous pm's so this is the only way I can do it. Only reason for doing this is that the group that houses the server where this current database is at wants to get out of the maintenance business of it.

Comment: VBA is deprecated and has been unsupported by Microsoft for half a decade I believe.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above I used Spock addition of dynamic lookup of values for the compare and value variable. Once I did that I added the hasExecuted flag.

```
Public Sub exportprojinfodata()

    Dim stSQL As String
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strConn As String
Dim iRowNo As Integer
Dim targetFieldNames As Variant
Dim rowData As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim sql As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim aField As String
Dim compare As Variant
Dim value As Variant
Dim hasExecuted As String


hasExecuted = False



With Sheets("Data2")

    lastrow = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    'Open a connection to SQL Server
   conn.Open _
        "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=PWIRTPAUDD1HV8;Initial Catalog=STAR;User Id=STAR_USER;Password=dcistarrtp"

    'Skip the header row
    iRowNo = 2

     targetFieldNames = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wks_TargetFieldNames.Range("TargetFieldNames").value), "," & vbNewLine)



     Do While iRowNo <= lastrow
        rowData = wks_ProjDescription.Range("A" & iRowNo & ":AO" & iRowNo).value


        compare = wks_ProjDescription.Range("B"& iRowNo).value

        'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table

            With rs
                .ActiveConnection = conn
                .Open "Select proj_id from dbo.STAR_DC_INITIAL_ProjectInfo_ExcelDevCopy where proj_id= " & compare
                wks_ProjDescription.Range("AX2").CopyFromRecordset rs
                .Close
            End With

            value = wks_ProjDescription.Range("AX"& iRowNo).value

            If compare = value And hasExecuted = False Then
                stSQL = "delete from dbo.STAR_DC_INITIAL_ProjectInfo_ExcelDevCopy where proj_id = " & value
                conn.Execute stSQL
                hasExecuted = True
            End If

        sql = "insert into dbo.STAR_DC_INITIAL_ProjectInfo_ExcelDevCopy ("
        sql = sql & targetFieldNames
        sql = sql & ") values (" & vbNewLine
```

'

```
        'couldn't do transpose since rowData represents a row, not a column
        For i = 1 To UBound(rowData, 2)
          aField = Replace(rowData(1, i), "'", "''")
                Select Case i
                    Case 1 To 40
                        sql = sql & "'" & aField & "', " & vbNewLine
                    Case 41
                        If aField Like "*,*" Then
                            sql = sql & "'" & """" & aField & """" & vbNewLine
                        Else
                            sql = sql & "'" & aField & "' " & vbNewLine
                        End If
                End Select


        Next i

       sql = sql & ");"
     '   sql = sql & "');"  

      conn.Execute sql

        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1

    Loop

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

    End With
End Sub
```